# Using GPIO 2 and 3 to close an external switch - can or should I link grounds?

Tags: gpio

If I have an external board which has 2 pins, ground and pin16 which I want to short (as would a mechanical switch) from the Pi, can I link grounds from the Pi to the external board and use the fact that pins 2 & 3 have pull up resistors on them, then send them low and that will effectively short the 2 pins on the external board?

The external board has this diagram:

[image]

COM is described Comun (-)  ..  Its in Spanish where Comun is Common in English.

And I would like to replace the switch show on pin 16 with a Pi:

[image]

Some other bits that I imagine are important.

Voltage on pin 16 when not connected = 12V

Current between pin 16 and Com when shorted 1mA (as well as I can measure it)

Comment: Please draw a circuit diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You CAN NOT use a Pi (or indeed ANY computer) to close a switch.

GPIO can output 3.3V or 0V.

You need to use a relay or similar although a transistor can often do the job.

Connecting a Pi to an unknown circuit is likely to result in a dead Pi. If the pin has 12V on it damage is almost inevitable.

Comment: Can't say clearer than that.  Thank you!